# Respository migration from one server to another

Tags: git

I recently(15 days aback) migrated one repository say from github(old) to bitbucket(new).
I used --mirror for that purpose.
While we all work on new repository at bitbucket, few people worked on old repository at github.
I want to get all the changes from old repo to new repo in last 15 days.
What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps i misunderstand the question, but can't you have the people who worked on the old github repo add the bitbucket one as a new remote, and just push to it?

Comment: the old person does not have access to new bitbucket and we plan to not have that person do any work for us in future

Comment: you could have him push his changes back to github.  then you pull the changes down to your local computer.  then you push them to bitbucket.  That way he never has access to bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to send pull request from bitbucket to github currently. Create a branch from bitbucket, clone the github and merge it with bitbucket. If you worked on the same files in github and bitbucket you will have conflicts. Resolve and push them to the bitbucket.